# Как рисовать картинки при помощи батча и в той же сцене отрисовывать tiledmap через OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer в libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

Когда я пытають отрисовать tiledmap и после этого рисую texture (batch.draw("объект Texture")) я вижу только tiledmap. Как мне решить эту проблемму?

не думаю что код тут чем-то поможет, но тем не менее:

Метод рендер в классе сцены:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    update();

    //В .show я указал цвет очистки
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
        camera.translate(hero, batch);

        joystick.render(batch);
        hero.render(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Метод Transate в классе камеры(этот класс двигает камеру за героем и делает параллакс из tiledmap):

```
    public void translate(Hero hero, SpriteBatch batch){

        // x translate
        if (hero.getVector().x - (int) camera.viewportWidth / 2 < 0) {
//            x = 0;
        } else if (hero.getVector().x + (int) camera.viewportWidth / 2 > mapWidth) {
//            x = mapWidth - (int) camera.viewportWidth;
        } else {
            x = (int) hero.getVector().x - (int) camera.viewportWidth / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < collisionLoader.length; i++) {
                if (hero.speed < 0){
                    collisionLoader[i].setOffsetX(collisionLoader[i].getOffsetX() - ((collisionLoader.length - i) * (Math.abs(hero.speed) / collisionLoader.length)));
                }else if (hero.speed > 0){
                    collisionLoader[i].setOffsetX(collisionLoader[i].getOffsetX() + (collisionLoader.length - i) * (hero.speed / collisionLoader.length));
                }

            }
        }

        // y translate
        if (hero.getVector().y - (int) camera.viewportHeight / 2 < 0) {
            y = 0;
        } else if (hero.getVector().y + (int) camera.viewportHeight / 2 > mapHeight) {
            y = mapHeight - (int) camera.viewportHeight;
        } else {
            y = (int) hero.getVector().y - (int) camera.viewportHeight / 2;
        }


        // camera update
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        // camera position translate
        camera.position.set(new Vector3(-x, -y, 0));
        camera.position.set(new Vector3(camera.viewportWidth - camera.position.x,
                                        camera.viewportHeight / 2 - 
                                        camera.position.y,
                                        0));

        // tiled render
        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();
    }
```

И если что, вот конструктор камеры:

```
public Camera(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, TiledMap map, 
                          OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer,
                          TiledMapTileLayer[] collisionLoader) {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(512, 288);

    this.map = map;
    this.renderer = renderer;

    this.mapWidth =  mapWidth;
    this.mapHeight = mapHeight;

    this.collisionLoader = collisionLoader;
    for (int i = 0; i < collisionLoader.length; i++){
        collisionLoader[i] = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(i);
        this.collisionLoader[i] = collisionLoader[i];
    }
}
```

В методе joystik.render(batch) как и в hero.render(batch) я просто отрисовываю картинку как обычную текстуру (код выкладывать нет смысла)

И при запуске проги я вижу только tiledmap

Если нужно будет весь код то скажите и я сделаю проект на гит хабе и скину ссылку

Спасибо!

Comment: Привет. Если еще не решил проблему, то выложи проект на гитхаб, яб глянул

Comment: кстати, забыл упомянуть: это приложение для андроид, но есть десктопный лончер

Comment: https://github.com/Nannik/Game

Comment: Репозиторий не открывается. Непубличный проект?

Comment: Сорян. уже открыл доступ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так в целом работает:

```
@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();

    batch.begin();
    hero.render(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

1. вынес `render.render()` перед `batch.begin()`
2. убрал `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);`

я хотел запушить бранч того как (по-моему получше), но прав не хватило. Сделал ПР из форка

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но как открыть доступ? просто хочу посмотреть как будет правильнее написать код

Comment: я отправил пул реквест в твой репозиторий из своего форка